# which kind of record this like will get?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
LIKE ',%,%,'
```

I am using above like in case statement to get record. But it's not working as expected.

My query is -

```
SELECT  
CASE 
        WHEN row_id LIKE ',%,%,'
            THEN 'A'
        WHEN row_id NOT LIKE ',%,%,'
            THEN ''
        END 'AF'
        FROM MyView WHERE row_id = '2464,2465,2466' 
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Expected Output - A getting blank.

Comment: Your `LIKE` pattern is matching _four_ elements in a comma-separated list, e.g. `1,2,3,4`, but your `row_id` only has three elements, and therefore two commas.

Comment: `',%,%,'` matches strings like `',2465,2466,' `

Comment: how to write a like where I will have data in row_id like 1,2,3,..n ?

Comment: I think you need [`PATINDEX()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) - like `PATINDEX('%,%', c) > 0 AND PATINDEX(',%', c) = 0 AND PATINDEX('%,', c) = 0` ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This like:

```
row_id LIKE ',%,%,'
```

will match every single row_id that starts and ends with a comma and has at least a comma in between.

Your query, because of the clause

```
WHERE row_id = '2464,2465,2466'
```

will always return an empty set because this row_id doesn't match the previous pattern.

Answer (score 1):

row_id LIKE ',%,%,' means a string that starts with `,` and contain a `,` and ends with `,`.

If you mean a string that contains two `,` or one `,` then try this:

```
SELECT  
CASE 
    WHEN row_id LIKE '%,%,%'
            THEN 'A'
    WHEN row_id NOT LIKE '%,%'
            THEN ''
    END 'AF'
FROM MyView WHERE row_id = '2464,2465,2466' 
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Comment: I can have n number of values in row_id separated by comma. I need to get A if it matched that pattern.

Comment: @Mukund the pattern is: if it contains comma, or not?